# Error in code when using Logical OR operator

Tags: c

I've started learning C programming language recently. I wanted to write a simple yes/no program, however, there is an error in my code that I cannot seem to find a solution to.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char answer[10];


printf("do you like programming? yes/no\n");
scanf(" %s", &answer);

if((answer == 'yes')|| (answer == 'no')){
    printf("you are awesome\n");
}
else{
    printf("try again\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

When I use y/n instead of yes/no, the program works fine.
I know that I need to replace char with string, but I do not know how to do that. I read somewhere that I need to use a function called strcmp, but I do not know how to use that either. If anyone could help me, I would be really grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i would suggest reading up on `strcmp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type
`if((answer == 'yes')|| (answer == 'no'))`, the `==` operator in this case is not comparing the strings, but instead the pointers to the strings. To test equality of the strings, use [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/). Your `if` statement would then look this this:

```
#include <string.h>

...

if(strcmp(answer, "yes") == 0 || strcmp(answer, "no") == 0) {

...
```